# How to correct this T-SQL syntax to get an output with no decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal, nvarchar

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have the following T-SQL code in my query:

```
CAST(ROUND([Count of Bookings] * 100.0 / SUM([Count of Bookings]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Market Final], [PropertyCode]), 0) AS NVARCHAR(15)) + '%'
```

An example of the current output of this code is: 40.000000000000%

I was expecting the output to be: 40%

As a note (I don't know if this is relevant): if I change the number in the `nvarchar(x)` to lower than 15, I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Comment: You dont want any decimal places ?

Comment: Either increase the size of your varchar or first convert it to an int to drop the trailing 0's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str()` instead of `cast()`:

```
str(round([Count of Bookings] * 100.0 /
          sum([Count of Bookings]) over(PARTITION BY [Market Final], [PropertyCode]
         ) , 0), 3, 0)  + '%'
```

Actually, I think `str()` rounds by default (could the documentation be any less clear on this subject?):

```
str([Count of Bookings] * 100.0 /
    sum([Count of Bookings]) over (PARTITION BY [Market Final], [PropertyCode]
                                  ), 3, 0)  + '%'
```

Comment: Works beautifully! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The return type of any input of the `ROUND()` function is depending on the input data type as you can see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx).

This causes your `ROUND()` to return a data type with a decimal point (in this calculation a `float`) that you will have to truncate after the conversion to `nvarchar` (or cast it to an `int` before).